# C#, ASP.NET - How can I Update UI, wait 5 seconds, Update UI again?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am using ASP.NET webforms.

What I am looking to do is

- execute a method that returns a string
- update label with that string
- wait 5 seconds
- execute method again
- update label with 2nd string
- repeat..

Comment: Why you are repeating the execution of the same method?

Comment: I'm passing in a different parameter each time.

Comment: Webforms works in request - response format. UI will not be updated until response received. You can achieve this kind of behaviour on the client side with exactly same steps, where "execute method" will be updating form or using AJAX for sending request. On server side this kind of scenario can be achieved with "push notifications" - check SignalR for example

Comment: Share your code and also point out the issue in code.

Comment: Hi ! It would be better if you checkout [Asking question format](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for future endeavor at Stack overflow. -Thank you

Comment: you need knockoutjs. you can update ui using that. we used it to update the time every seconds that displays in the page

Answer (score 0):

you can load your page after specific time using below line of code in
head section

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10"/>
```

content=10 tells the time delay after which the page gets reloaded. but please specify your problem to write code so that i can understand properly

Answer (score 0):

If your "Method" needs to be executed Server Side then you can send Ajax Requests every 5 seconds or you can you use Signal R to push the results every 5 seconds. Check this link for Signal R:
 [Using Websockets through SignalR to broadcast data from Server to Client](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/853368/Using-Task-Factory-to-increase-the-performance-of)

If your method needs to be executed client side, then you can use setInterval:

```
setInterval(function() {
  // method to be executed;
}, 5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that you want to execute a method in the controller every 5 seconds so your view gets updatet? I don't know how you're passing a different parameter each time but I try to answer your question.

If you are using C# ASP.net you mostly try to avoid HTML or Javascript for this kind of actions. So I am using this to reload my HttpGet method from my controller:

```
Response.AppendHeader("Refresh", "5;url=/Home/" + MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name);
```

"`MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name`" = the name of your method,
"5;" is the number of seconds before it refreshes.

If the method name is not the same as your view name then just use a string.